# Linked list Advice

Tags: c#, list

I've been given a task as follows:

I'd like to to build an implementation of a Linked List.  Specifically I'd like it to be a doubly linked list.

My task:
Your program should use the linked list to model a train route using the linked list.
First the user will enter as many stops as they'd like the train to have, and the name of each stop.
The program should then print a map of the route.
Once finished they then enter the name of the stop they want to start at.
From there they can enter commands to move the train either forward to the next stop or backward to the previous one.

I've been told I'm not doing this task right but I don't really understand how not, I'd appreciate it if someone could explain what I'm not doing that I should be doing.

My Route class (it isn't finished but it would've been nearly finished if it was done correctly):

```
namespace TrainRoute
{
    class Route
    {

        Stops root;

        public LinkedList<Stops> linkedList = new LinkedList<Stops>();
        public Stops MakeNewStop(string stopName)
        {
            Stops stopWithStopName = new Stops(stopName);
            return stopWithStopName;
        }


        public void AddStops(Stops stopIWantToAdd)
        {
            if (linkedList.Count == 0)
            {
                linkedList.AddFirst(stopIWantToAdd);
            }
            else
            {
                //stopIWantToAdd.prevStop = linkedList.Last();
                linkedList.AddLast(stopIWantToAdd);
            }
        }
        public void StopRelationships()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < linkedList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>(i).nextStop == null && linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>((i + 1)) != null)
                {
                    linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>(i).nextStop = linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>((i + 1));
                }
                if (linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>((i - 1)) != null)
                {
                    linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>(i).prevStop = linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>(i - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            if (linkedList != null)
            {

                foreach (var item in linkedList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Stop name: " + item.stopName);
                }
            }
        }


        public int StopPosition(string usersInput)
        {
            int position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < linkedList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>(i).stopName == usersInput)
                {
                    position = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return position;
        }
        public int MoveForward(int indexPosition)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The train is now at " +linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>(indexPosition).nextStop.stopName);
            return (indexPosition + 1);
        }

        public int MoveBackwords(int indexPosition)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The train is now at " + linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>(indexPosition).prevStop.stopName);
            return (indexPosition - 1);
        }

        public bool VerifyRoute(int indexPosition, string prevOrForward)
        {
            if (prevOrForward.Contains("forward"))
            {
                if (linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>((indexPosition+1)) != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if (linkedList.ElementAt<Stops>((indexPosition-1)) != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also not allowed to use the Linked list class but I'm to use a linked list (I'm not 100% sure what that means).

Any and all advice/help provided will be appreciated!

Comment: Was your task to **use** a linked list, or **implement** a linked list?

Comment: It sounds like your teacher (assuming this is homework) expects you to implement a linked list class, not use the provided .NET class.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I just asked and got a very confusing answer but luckily at the end he said the best way to learn how to use something is to build it so Implement. Well that instantly makes all of my code useless :(

Comment: @user3245390: Not necessarily, but undoubtedly it will need some major reworking.

Comment: Agree with the other commenters but really, you should clarify this with your teacher (to get max points). Clarifying requriements is a big part of software engineering that is often not done well. So, look at it as practice... For the record, I agree with Matt above, You need to implement a linked list `MyLinkedList` with appropriate API to complete the requirement. Your requirement is to be able to record a train route and then return the route on request. When thinking about the implementation, draw pictures with nodes and pointers and work out how they are moved. Reuse them too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's piece together the breadcrumbs here:

> I'd like to to build an implementation of a Linked List.

and this:

> I'm also not allowed to use the Linked list class

Obviously the task here is for you to implement your own linked list (class), and not to use the existing one provided by .NET.

I'm assuming here the task is not to build the program handling the trains, but instead to learn how a linked list works, and how you would go about implementing one.

As such, your shortcut to simply grab the existing class is the wrong tool for the job. It would be perfect (probably) if your task was to build that program, but in this case the program is orthogonal to your task, it's there to create a context for what you're really asked to do:

Implement your own version of `LinkedList<T>` (though you probably don't need to make it generic).

Wikipedia has a [very good article on linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) if you're stumped on how such a data structure really works. There's undoubtedly other very good resources out on the net as well, and probably in your text book or other resources.

Additionally, I would urge you to find a classmate to peer with, from experience I can say that most of the really hard problems I've had in my programming career has (usually) been solved by having a sparring partner to work with.

Comment: It seems it was me misunderstanding the task at hand.. yet again. I'm kind of lucky and not so lucky as I already kind of know how to do this since I've done a little bit of Binary Search tree code. but as I'm not in education (apprenticeship) I don't actually have help apart from stackoverflow :(. Luckily the people on stack are overflow are very helpful. Thanks for the help, I'll accept you're answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a linked list isn't that difficult. I assume you have a textbook and it discusses linked list, read it, *carefully*. Also you want to clarify with your tutor exactly how much functionality your linked list needs to implement.

Basically, you'll start with a `node` class, if you don't need it to be generic, then you can create a `StopNode` class. The basics of your `node` class will be a reference to the next node in the list and, since this is a doubly linked list, a reference to the previous node:

```
public class StopNode
{
    public StopNode Next { get; set; }
    public StopNode Previous { get; set; }
    // whatever other properties your stop class needs - such as name
}
```

Now your LinkedList class will manage the collection of stop nodes. It will need to keep a reference to the first or "head" node and probably the last node too (or "tail").

```
public class StopLinkedList
{
     private StopNode Head { get; }
     private StopNode Tail { get; }
}
```

And it will need to implement methods to add and remove nodes (at a minimum) and probably also insert.

Add is pretty easy - check if Head is null. If it is, just set Head and Tail both equal to your new node. If it's not, you will instead set the `Next` property of your `Tail` to your new node, then set the `Previous` of your new node to the `Tail` and then finally update your `Tail` to reference your new node.

To remove a node, if given the node to remove, you will need to check it's `Previous` and `Next` properties and (assuming one or both isn't null - you'll need to add logic for that), you set your nodes `Previous.Next` to your nodes `Next` and your nodes `Next.Previous` to your nodes `Previous`. This will cause your node to fall out of the list (you can set your nodes `Next` and `Previous` to null if required, but it's not strictly necessary unless your removed node is going to hang around).

Hopefully that gets you started. Clarify with your tutor, check your textbook (probably better to try and match their terminology if it differs from mine) and also search for "linked list" and "doubly linked list" on the internet. You should find plenty of resources.

Comment: Hi, I'll post my code so far in the OP and maybe you can lemme know how it is (I have an error but I'll post that in the OP. I don't have a tutor and text books unfortunately. The dev told me it'd probably be best to use recursion so I'm going to use that to keep him happy. Edit: I can't post it in the OP :(.